# Cucumber-JVM: Cucumber After hook executed two times/twice

Tags: selenium, testng, cucumber-jvm

I"m implemnet Cucumber Testng for learning purposes. I"m realizes that @After hook method is executed twice. I can confirm it with debugging set and test report output. I"m only execute 1 feature file and my test report has two same class names.

Do you guys know why?
There is warning in the feature file called Multiple Definitions "Volare Collector Home Page opens in browser".

[image: Test Report shows there are two features executed]

Please help. Thanks.
Please download my source code from this [link](http://www.dropbox.com/s/4wvqczqa99j0ael/Cucumber_TestNG.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Perhaps you can upload your code to github and share the link. Not many people are comfortable downloading zip files.

Comment: Please share the code you have used, else it would be difficult to get a resolution